# Generate forum signatures from data

Tags: java, reporting

I'd like to generate forum signatures similar to this one:

[image: Signature]

What are the best tools and frameworks that would help me produce such images easier and looking more visually appealing?

Ideally, this would be done in the "Java world" but I'm open to using other technologies as well.

Charts functionality is a bonus. WYSIWYG editor likewise.

The images will be fixed size.

What I've considered so far:

- Jasper Reports - this would work, and generally has pixel perfect layout, but I've used it before and hated the tooling - getting the visual appeal will be very difficult. It's optimized for "big PDF report of company financials" and not this.
- JavaFX / AWT "app" with a custom Java charting library, render to buffered image. Again, optimized for a different use case (interactive applications). Headless mode on Linux where it would run in production may have visual glitches.
- Do it in HTML/CSS, render using WebDriver (?), somehow capture the result. Seems a very heavy-weight way to get there, may be challenging. Nice charts libraries available.
- Just create a BufferedImage and draw to its Graphics. Straightforward, but I was really hoping for a more higher level abstraction.

What am I missing?

Comment: Is this an interactive, real-time dashboard, or a static image?

Comment: It's a static .png image. Possibly an animated .gif, but that's probably not.